# Simplify fit function in MATLAB with handle

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, function-handle

I want to fit some data with MATLAB but my fit-function is pretty large
and I just want to put it into pieces of functions.

At first I just tried it like

```
p1_prime = @(x,p) ...
p2_prime = @(x,p) ...
```

Then I put it into my model function

```
mod = D*exp(-p1_prime) + D*(-p2_prime)
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The first step, generating the `mod` function, just needs some syntax help:

```
%Instead of this
mod=D*exp(-p1_prime)+D*(-p2_prime)

%Use this
mod = @(x,p) D*exp( -p1_prime(x,p) )+D*( -p2_prime(x,p) )
```

Function handle operations are not overloaded as required for your initial line of code to work.

In terms of getting this into a curve fitting routine, we'd need to see more about what you are trying to do.